# Regex expression to accept alphanumeric characters and only one @ symbol

Tags: javascript, regex

I am wrting a javascript if the accepted value is other than alphanumeric characters and symbols _.-@ , it should throw an alert.

I have used below expression, however concern is that I need only one mandate occurence of @ symbol. How can I do that?

```
!/^[ A-Za-z0-9_.-@]*$/
```

Comment: Can you give some sample inputs and whether they should be matched?

Comment: you could check if the value contains the @ `str.contains('@')` if it is okay to not be 100% regex

Comment: Try `/^[ A-Za-z0-9_.-]*@[ A-Za-z0-9_.@-]*$/`. If the `@` can only appear once, use `/^[ A-Za-z0-9_.-]*@[ A-Za-z0-9_.-]*$/`. It would be best if you could supply some strings that should be (in)?valid.

Comment: Are you trying to write a regex to validate an email address? There are plenty of these online if you google for them (and if you are not trying to do an email address, still google for an email regex and see how it works - they will all only allow 1 `@` character)

Comment: matching strings can be - risha123@ however strings like risha@@ or risha should not be acceptable. So, @ is mandatory and should occur once only. @meagar

Comment: @Risha What about `a@b`, `ab@` and `@ab`? Are these all valid?

Comment: @Risha I see from your comments below that you *are* trying to validate email addresses. **Don't do this**. Email cannot be effectively validated with a regular expression. You need to validate the email by delivering mail to it, and confirming that the user received the email by opening an activation link, *not* by using a regular expression. Everything you've described so far is *wrong* and will fail for many valid email addresses.

Comment: Regular expressions work if you only care about format, and not if it is an existing email or not.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn No, they really don't. You can *at best* check that **at least one** `@` appears, anything else is likely to be wrong. Email address validation needs to be *extremely* permissive, and rely on delivering mail to the address.

Answer (score 4):

You could look for as many accepted characters that aren't '@', then look for exactly one '@', followed by any amount of accepted characters again. The `\w` metacharacter will also replace your `A-Za-z0-9_` portion, so you can use the following:

```
!/^[ \w.-]*@[ \w.-]*$/
```

Comment: For the sake of shortness `^[ \w.-]*@[ \w.-]*$`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I edited my answer to include this

Comment: It did not work for me. matching strings can be - risha123@ however strings like risha@@ or risha should not be acceptable. So, @ is mandatory and should occur once only. @jacob

Comment: @Risha I have updated my answer to search for a mandatory single occurrence of the @ symbol

Comment: @Risha it matches https://regex101.com/r/wajPbT/1 as you can see only the second line is matched

Comment: It didn't match `risha@@` for me

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I verified correctly, It works for me. @revo I am at the learning stage, we all can make mistakes, that's why we are here. :)

Comment: @revo, I did not insist, please check my comment above and many thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If it is okay to not be completely Regex driven, you can use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to see if the `@` is already in the string. If it is we don't allow it otherwise we do allow it.

If the character isn't a `@` we then test it against the regex.

```js
document.getElementById('input-test').addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  let value = e.currentTarget.value
  let key = e.key
  if ((value.includes('@') && key == '@') || !!key.match(/[\sA-Za-z0-9_.\-@]/) === false) e.preventDefault()
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-test">
```

Comment: I have used a simple Javascript -                                                         Risha_EmailValidation ()

{

var Name = serviceForm.Risha_Dict_1.Emailaddress.getValue();

if (!/^[ A-Za-z0-9_.-@]*$/.test(Name))
{
 alert("Email address can contain alphanumeric characters and the symbols- Hyphen (-), underscore (_) or period (.). It must contain one @ symbol.");
}
 
}

Comment: @Risha That's not true at all for email address. They can contain `+`, as well as *tends of thousands* of other characters. Bad email validations are horrible for your users, please rethink your approach.

Comment: it is not for end user experience, it is for research purpose and i have to do it through regex only. @meagar